# Windows Server 2008/2012 with 2 public IP, how bind .exe to particular IP

Tags: windows, ip, bind, interface, adapter

On Windows Server 2008 R2 or 2012, if I have 2 public IP, how can I manage applications to use first or second IP? Can Windows Server do this (like via Properties on .exe file) or this is possible only if this is implemented in application?
If this is not possible, which IP address will be use applications as default?

I found only one app, ForceBindIP, I don't know if this will work on Windows Server, but I need exactly what this app can do, bind application to IP/network adapter.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

The application would need to be configured to use one of the available interfaces/IPs in the system. If the application lacks that ability, then it will use whichever interface comes first in the system-wide NIC binding order.

If you can't change the NIC binding order of the system, consider a virtualization solution. Create a VM and a virtual switch, and connect that virtual switch to whatever physical NIC you want. Then connect the VM that's running your app to that vSwitch.

Answer (score 1):

I recall reading in Windows Server documentation that there is no way for Windows to tell an application to use a specific IP address. This is a function that would have to be rolled into the specific application.